# Can we store complex POJO objects in Ignite Key-Value Cache?

Tags: ignite

I have few pojos in my project, these pojo are complex in the sense that, the pojos has references to jdbc connections, threads, spring application context, other spring beans.

Can we store such object / objects in ignite cache?

Comment: Why do you need to store such entries? How should they retain meaning when used on different nodes?

Comment: I understand if you use caching like Apache Ignite  / Redis, the objects to be stored should be POJO. I am bound to store and its not working, fixing it would require huge amount of refactoring of the code which is nearly impossible (without breaking the code and keeping the functionality intact).

Comment: I am running only one ignite instance, and one such object got stored, but on getting it back from ignite,throws un-marshaling exception. Upon refactoring, removing the database code and loggers it worked. But later I got stuck with other object which is more complex than earlier one.

Comment: My recommendation still stands. If you have no control over data classes, I'd say it's not doable, or at least you will need to invent your own serialization framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you must, you can implement `Externalizable`, and perform binding-unbinding of external resources in `writeExternal`/`readExternal`.

Comment: My whole and sole objective is to store user data, implementing `Externalizable` is not required.